# Live action assign and reassign id to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box that looks like:

```
<select class="span12 select" data-placeholder="Wybierz operacje" tabindex="2" id="contract-operations">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1" data-url="<?php echo $aggregate_url; ?>" data-id="aggregate_invoice">
    Wystaw fakturę dla zaznaczonych kontraktów
  </option>
  <option value="2" data-url="<?php echo $notification_url; ?>" data-id="">
    Awizacja do klienta
  </option>
  <option value="3" data-url="<?php echo $notification_cost_url; ?>" data-id="">
    Awizacja do klienta z potwierdzeniem
  </option>
</select>
```

under it there is a link that attributes href and id are assigned dynamic and it looks like:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-large contract-operations" href="#">
  <b class="icon-circle-arrow-up"></b>Wykonaj operacje dla zaznaczonych kontraktów
</a>
```

now depend on what option you choose from select box, id and href will change. Problem is with Id's, they are not working after attr assign any of them from js script that looks simple like:

```
select: function()
{
  $.obj.$select.on('change', function(){
    button.href  = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
    var id = $(this).find(':selected').data('id');

    $.obj.$a.attr('href', button.href);
    $.obj.$a.attr('id', id);
  });
}
```

They are assigning to a href element correctly but when I try to use those id's in another script or function it is like they never were assign.

Comment: Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: firstly, you shouldn't change ID of any element. Secondly, anyway, i guess you need to delegate event

Comment: Why does the anchor require an id?

Comment: Does [this code](http://codepad.org/YaLZwynS) work for you?

Answer (score -1):

use following

```
$(document).on('change','.select',function(){
     var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
     $('a.btn-info').attr({href:url});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/8H49X/2/

```
$(document).on('change', '.select', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedURL = $(this).children('option:selected').data('url');
    alert(selectedURL);
    $('a.btn-info').prop('href', selectedURL);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use on instead of delegate- it's been superseded.

```
$(document).on('change','.select', function()
{
  $('a.btn-info').prop('href',$(this).attr('data-url'));
$('a.btn-info').prop('id',$(this).children('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('data-id'));    });
```

});

What this does is bind the event "change" to the document instead of the ".select" elements. Then the 2nd argument is a selector which is what the event actually acts on. The 3rd is a typical event handler.

Rather than altering the element's id, which is generally static and unique, I would recommend adding another class instead. You can use .addClass, like so:

```
$(document).on('change','.select', function()
{
  $('a.btn-info').addClass($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8H49X/6/

Comment: As a side note: `delegate` is not deprecated but it has been superseded by the `.on()` method which usually is the step before beeing deprecated

Comment: i have created a fiddle with your answer and its not working.. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/8H49X/4/

Comment: I'll look into that. Just so you know, Stack Overflow recommends the use of the down vote for "whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." Give us a change to fix our mistakes before doing so, please.

Comment: This has been fixed. It's a convoluted solution, but frankly yours is a convoluted problem.

Comment: Why are you suggesting document level delegation? OP doesn't seem to need such things.